# create short mongoose id for schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Mongoose documents states that we can create a custom _id value instead of using default Object(...) id .

```
var User = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id : { type: String, unique: true },
    name: {type: String},
    device_os: {type: String},
    added_on: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});


User.pre('save', function(done) {
  _id = new Date().toString(8);
  console.log("inside save pre",_id);
  done();
});
```

This is not creating new document with custom _id field. Anything i m doing wrong over here ?

Comment: Try `this._id = new Date....`

Comment: Or `_id : { type : 'String', unique : true, default : function() { return new Date().toString(8) } }` (although I'm not sure what that "8" is supposed to do...).

Comment: @Molda : this._id worked

Comment: @robertklep :  it didn't worked...saving the entire function as id :(
anyways thanks for the help guys ...

Comment: update for @robertklep comment: `return new Date().getTime().toString(8)` when save document `_id: 26022637154456`